# Open excel template and save file

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want to open a excel template with a browse button, the file needs to open and must be directly saved by the user. after the file is saved the file location needs to be displayed in a textbox.

With this i can open excel itself, but i don't know how to open the template and save the document

```
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim Worksheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Worksheet2 As Excel.Worksheet

Private Sub BrowseExcelfilenaam_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseExcelfilenaam.Click
   Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Xl.Workbooks.Open("location\Geluidscherm_template.xls")
        Xl.Visible = True
        ExcelFilepath = Xl.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")

        Excelfilenaam.Text = (ExcelFilepath)
End Sub
```

The file opens and i get a save as dialog, but when i want to save the document it doesn;t save at all, However it won't give me a error.

Comment: Are they editing the actual template file or are they creating a new file based on the template file?

Comment: They file needs to be saved before they can work on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objApp As New Excel.Application

Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = objApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

objApp.Visible = True
```